# Series intersection?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I apologize for the title, I wasn't sure what else to call it.

A number X is chosen at random from the series 2,5,8,... and another number Y is chosen at random from the series 3,7,11,... Each series has 100 terms. Find P[X=Y].

I basically bruteforced and counted every number... It was 25. There were 100 x 100 possible pairs so $(100)^2$ possibilities.

$$25 \over 10000$$

I was wondering if there was a more simple or elegant way to solve this problem? In a timed environment, I don't think my method is very practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an "easy" way to brute force this. Basically, the first term the two sequences have in common is 11. Because the common differences of the two sequences are 3 and 4, there is a common term every 12. This means that, looking at the first sequence, the terms in the positions $4, 8, 16, \dots 100$ are also found in the other sequence. This is where the $25$ in the numerator comes from.(Note that I had to consider the sequence with the smaller common difference when counting this)

Comment: I see what you're saying, thank you!